# Super slow index scan from IN subquery (generated by third party software). Tuning postgres or rewriting query?

Tags: postgresql, index

I have a query which has a huge bottleneck. Doing explain analyze I found out that an index scan is causing the problem.

The query is:

```
select * from product where (product.id = IN(select pu.id from product_user pu where pu.userid = 123)) limit 40
```

So the mytable.id = IN() causes an index scan which is really slow. After some searching on the internet I found that rewriting the query like this..

```
select * from product where (product.id = ANY((SELECT ARRAY(select pu.id from product_user pu where pu.userid = 123)::bigint[]))) limit 40
```

..performs way better, like 70% faster. Please note that the subquery (standalone) is super fast, but does return like 300k records.

Also, adding a manual btree index on the primary key (ID) column of the product table does increase performance a bit as well. Not sure why this is faster than the default primary key index.

Here's the full original query + query plan: https://explain.depesz.com/s/UW1w > Here's the same a bit more readable with a few strings translated: https://explain.depesz.com/s/Ry99#query

Here's the one with ANY(SELECT ARRAY.. instead of IN: https://explain.depesz.com/s/DS33

The query is generated by third party software. I have almost no influence on this query. Is there any way to either:

1. Tune postgres so the index scan from the IN() subquery will be faster
2. Rewrite a query right before execution on database level. We host the postgres database in the Google Cloud (managed databases), some kind of interceptor, does it exist?

Additional info:

- Postgres 13
- Total size of mytable: 9.000.000 rows
- Total size of subquery: +-300.000 rows

Any tips and suggestions are very welcome! Thanks!

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Comment: Thanks, added more info and full query + explain info

Comment: FWIW, a simple `JOIN` between `product` and `product_user` would probably be the best way to re-write it. Unfortunately for you, re-writing the query sounds unlikely. The best outcome would come from convincing the 3rd party software to fix their crappy code though.

Comment: Yeah, that's going to be a problem :) There is actually some login behind why the query is this way, but in certain scenarios it's just super inefficient. Altough I also don't get why Postgres is this inefficient in chosing the best plan. As I turn off "enable_nestloop" for example the query is way faster.

Comment: @Marcel Long `IN` lists as part of a predicate are a common problem for most RDBMS - it's not a PostgreSQL specific problem. They are the equivalent of a bunch of `OR` clauses. It just complicates the query too much. I actually consider them an anti-pattern. I can't think of a single reason where your example query would be any different as a `JOIN` though, btw.

Comment: Ok, but rewriting it as = ANY(ARRAY) speeds it up significantly. Not sure what changes under the hood but sounds like something Postgres could optimze. But probably this only works in specific cases.

There are no ways that you know of to intercept a query and rewrite it for example, on database level? Or not even rewrite, if only I could turn "enable_nestloop" off for this specific query that would already be a huge win. Turning this off globally will probably backfire.

Comment: Your plans do not match your queries, so it is rather hard to figure out what is going on.  Are your tables actually views?  Having your underlying table names look like secure passwords is not doing anyone any favors here.

Comment: Hi @jjanes, thanks for the help but not sure what you mean. Please check: https://explain.depesz.com/s/UW1w#html for a full example. Check the query tab for the original query. In my post I did simplify it, but in the link is the full query which for sure matches the explain plan. I understand the tablenames are a bit messy, but it's probably because it's partially in dutch.

Comment: Ps. it's just regular tables, no views. If you want I can make the query + plan readable by renaming the tables. I just thought to give the full original example would be best in case I need to post more results/tests

Comment: Quick update: there is significant performance improvement in PG15 over PG13. Like 3 times faster.. Plan looks the same though.

Comment: Your query seems to be over 2 tables, but your plan is over 3.  And I don't know which of your 2 tables in the query lines up with "c3gebruikerbeheer...." in the plan.  Renaming the tables to be more comprehensible (in English anyway) in the query text *is* a nice thought, but when they no longer match the names in the plan I think that doing that backfires.

Comment: I did a find replace on a few strings in both the plan and query so they match up. Please check: https://explain.depesz.com/s/Ry99 for a more readable version.